# Favicon.js vs favicon.ico in static() with staticCache() using Connect in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I just rewrote my nodeJS server code to take advantage of Connect's modular structure. That said, in looking at some of the code, I feel like using the favicon.js module to serve the favicon.ico file wouldn't be as efficient as using the static.js with staticCache.js modules (since I only have a couple static files that would never be replaced by any others in the cache). Would anybody be willing to confirm/deny this? I wouldn't be surprised if I'm just completely mistaken, hence my wanting to check.

Here's a link to the github page with all the modules for convenience's sake: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/tree/master/lib/middleware

Best,
Sami

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [favicon middleware for Connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/master/lib/middleware/favicon.js) is more than enough, look at these lines:

```
headers: {
    Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'
  , 'Content-Length': buf.length
  , 'ETag': '"' + utils.md5(buf) + '"'
  , 'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=' + (maxAge / 1000)
}
```

You have both the 'Cache-Control' and the 'Etag' headers set, what more would you need for a favicon.. ?